# help to write a custom php script to settingup yoast priority to pages or posts

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, customization

I'm trying to improve this tutorial [script](http://chykalophia.com/wordpress/change-yoast-sitemap-frequency-and-priority/) including a `switch` in the first `if`condition to assign a custom `priority` to my *Yoast Xml Sitemap* only to certain post or pages.

So i'm trying to say to Yoast which **if some pages have certain `id` the  `priority` have to change,** but my script assign the 0.5 value to all pages.

Any help?

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_priority', 'my_custom_post_xml_priority', 10, 3 );

function my_custom_post_xml_priority( $return, $type, $post) {

if($type == 'page') {
switch ($post) {
case '8':
case '395':
case '342':
$return = 0.9;
case '5':
$return = 1.00;
case '620':
case '703':
case '603':
case '688':
case '695':
case '614':
case '684':
case '639':
case '628':
case '539':
case '542':
case '521':
case '509':
case '517':
case '528':
case '533':
case '536':
case '548':
case '545':
case '525':
case '551':
$return = 0.7;
break;
default:
$return = 0.5;
break;
}
}

elseif ($type == 'post') {
$return = 0.8;
}

return $return;
}
```

Comment: Is `$post` really a number formatted as a string?

Comment: Following the [tutorial](http://chykalophia.com/wordpress/change-yoast-sitemap-frequency-and-priority/) it seems to use  `$post ` to get the post `id`.

Comment: If you see the `', 10, 3 );` it means the 3rd `$post` parameter it's a post object so i'm be able to use `$post -> ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should is this:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_priority', 'my_custom_post_xml_priority', 10, 3 );

function my_custom_post_xml_priority( $return, $type, $post) {

    if($type == 'page') {
        switch ($post->ID) {
        case '8':
        case '395':
        case '342':
            $return = 0.9;
            break;
        case '5':
            $return = 1.00;
            break;
        case '620':
        case '703':
        case '603':
        case '688':
        case '695':
        case '614':
        case '684':
        case '639':
        case '628':
        case '539':
        case '542':
        case '521':
        case '509':
        case '517':
        case '528':
        case '533':
        case '536':
        case '548':
        case '545':
        case '525':
        case '551':
            $return = 0.7;
            break;
        default:
            $return = 0.5;
            break;
        }
    } elseif ($type == 'post') {
        $return = 0.8;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

I think that `$post` is an [WP_Post object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), then you will have to compare the property ID on the switch.

Comment: Nice! Perfect solution!